# JSON to HTML in ruby

Tags: html, json, ruby, sinatra

I have some data that is being displayed in JSON format as shown below. I want to convert this JSON data into HTML table/format. Can someone tell me what options I have, I am using Ruby and Sinatra as the framework?

```
{"id"=>123456, "documentKey"=>"xyz", "globalId"=>"xyz", "itemType"=>1234,
"project"=>123, "createdDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000",
"modifiedDate"=>"2015-02-20T00:11:56.000+0000",
"lastActivityDate"=>"2016-03-02T16:23:52.000+0000",
"createdBy"=>1234, "modifiedBy"=>12342,
"fields"=>{"name"=>"Introduction",
           "globalId"=>"Text",
           "documentKey"=>"Text-2",
           "description"=>"Some introduction"
          }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What is the desired result of this table? This [Example](https://repl.it/KDlc/1) will make a "table" and nest a "table" for the `:fields` key. I have no idea if that is what is "desired"

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you for that. The desired result is that I want to output this JSON data in a PDF file. The above example has sample data, but in my application it has requirements which I want to print to a PDF format. So, someone suggested that I first transfer my JSON data in html and then to PDF.

Comment: You may need a templating language to do that. Standard in ruby is [erb](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) which probably is the easiest to use if you are new to this kind of thing. Most of the options for sinatra is available in the [README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

Yous json looks like it may come from a database. And if that is happening in your sinatra/ruby code you should probably work with the database object directly rather than go *via* json.